# Find Floquet multiplier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\dot u=f(u)$ with $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is an ODE. Know that $\gamma(t)$ is a $T$-periodic solution. The linearization about $\gamma(t)$ is
$$\dot u=f_u(\gamma(t))u.$$
Let the transition matrix of the linearized ODE to be $\Phi(t,0)$. Find the eigenvalues of $\Phi(T,0)$ (i.e. Floquet multipliers).

First, $1$ is an eigenvalue since $\dot \gamma(t)$ satisfies the linearization and hence $$\Phi(T,0)\dot\gamma(T)=\Phi(T,0)\dot\gamma(0)=\dot\gamma(T).$$

I have difficulties finding the second Floquet multiplier. The hint says that the answer should be in the form involving only $\gamma(t)$ and $f(u)$ or its derivatives.

I've tried writing $\Phi(t,0)=P(t)e^{Bt}$ and come up with some clever functions so that hopefully with manipulation has the form $\Phi(T,0)\theta(c)=\lambda(t)\theta(c)$. However, neither approach has lead me anywhere.